# Using Golang how to get the number of transactions in a block

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

I cant seem to find any way to get the number or transactions within a block using the block number in golang.. anyone have any idea how to do this

Answer (score 2):

To get the number of transactions in a block you can use `client.TransactionCount(...)` or `len(block.Transactions())`. Here's a full example:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/big"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)

func main() {
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://mainnet.infura.io")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    header, err := client.HeaderByNumber(context.Background(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    blockNumber := big.NewInt(5671744)
    block, err := client.BlockByNumber(context.Background(), blockNumber)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(len(block.Transactions()))   // 144

    count, err := client.TransactionCount(context.Background(), block.Hash())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(count) // 144
}
```

For more examples, check out the [Ethereum Development with Go](https://github.com/miguelmota/ethereum-development-with-go-book) guide book.